# Payouts errors on Sandbox

Tags: rest, paypal

I am trying to create Payout functionality using REST API, and I have few errors.

While I am sending this request :

```
{"sender_batch_header":{"sender_batch_id":"test_0","email_subject":"RaceBets Withdrawal","recipient_type":"PAYPAL_ID"},"items":[{"recipient_type":"PAYPAL_ID","amount":{"currency":"EUR","value":"20.0"},"receiver":"XXXX","note":"Hello there!","sender_item_id":"71292226"}]}
```

I received:

```
JAXBException occurred : 4 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions.
```

or :

```
{"name":"REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING","message":"Access token does not have required scope.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING"}
```

the second error is also strange, because payments are working fine, and scope is also fine

```
{"scope":"https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks openid https://uri.paypal.com/services/invoicing https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*","access_token":"xxx","token_type":"Bearer","app_id":"APP-xxx","expires_in":28800}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second error make sure you have checked the option for "payouts" under your application at developer.paypal.com .

Go to developer.paypal.com --> DashBoard --> My APP -- > Click your APP Name --> App Feature . Select Payout here .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING error, I experienced this as well.  Adding the scope as the other poster describes fixed the issue.

Please note that after changing scope (i.e. adding Payouts) it can take a **few hours** for the change to be reflected, so you'll continue getting the error for awhile.  This confused me when I was testing because I didn't expect sandbox to have this latency.