# paypal batch payout php sdk 403 authorization error

Tags: php, paypal

I'am  trying a Paypal batch payment php sdk which i clone from https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/tree/master/sample/payouts. In the The payout is working when I try it the developer app credentials shipped with the sdk code. But when I try payout with my own app clientID and app secret , it gives me an `AUTHORIZATION_ERROR(403)`.

```
    {"name":"AUTHORIZATION_ERROR",
"message":"Authorization error occurred",
"debug_id":"a5a51a22c379f",
"information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#AUTHORIZATION_ERROR"}
```

I had enabled payouts in the sandbox account too. `I don't have any code to post here as the code was working with one set of app credentials`. I guess it has something to do with my app settings.Can any one tell me what I would have missed probably?

I don't see anything else to be changed in the sdk class other than the app credentials

Answer (score 0):

This may be an obvious question, but has PayPal authorized your use of the PayOut API? There's another reference to a similar issue here: [Payouts errors on Sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820168/payouts-errors-on-sandbox)

Comment: Not sure whether its an authorized lib. But I got it working when I used a app credentials created using a paid account

Comment: @ViPiN Do you mean that it started working when you signed up for the $30 per month "pro" account? May I ask if it is a U.S. account? I ask because I am having similar problems not being able to use the Payouts API.

Comment: Yes I went for a pro account